# I have written JavaScript code to fetch lectures of a particular day but I am not getting how to link my jQuery to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

This is a JavaScript function to get today's lectures of a chosen section of a class we have used jQuery for that. I am getting the array of today's classes using JavaScript, but how to implement this array on html file?

```js
//function to get today
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
  dd = '0' + dd
}

if (mm < 10) {
  mm = '0' + mm
}

today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var d = new Date(today);
var dayName = days[d.getDay()];
var section = 2;
console.log(dayName)
console.log(section)

function fetchCominUp(day, sec) {
  if (sec === 1) {
    if (day === "Monday") {
      var classes = new Array();
      classes[0] = "CG";
      classes[1] = "DW";
      classes[2] = "CD";
      classes[3] = "CN";
      return classes;
    }
    if (day === "Tuesday") {
      var classes = new Array();
      classes[0] = "CD";
      classes[1] = "CN";
      classes[2] = "DW-Lab A & CG-Lab B";
      classes[3] = "CG-Lab B & DW-Lab b";
      return classes;
    }
    if (day === "Wednesday") {
      var classes = new Array();
      classes[0] = "Apti";
      classes[1] = "Apti";
      classes[2] = "DW";
      classes[3] = "CG";
      return classes;
    }
    if (day === "Thursday") {
      var classes = new Array();
      classes[0] = "IM";
      classes[1] = "CN";
      classes[2] = "CD";
      classes[3] = "IS";
      return classes;
    }
    if (day === "Friday") {
      var classes = new Array();
      classes[0] = "DW";
      classes[1] = "CG";
      classes[2] = "CN-Lab A & CD-Lab B";
      classes[3] = "CD-Lab B & CN-Lab B";
      return classes;
    }
    if (day === "Saturday") {
      var classes = new Array();
      classes[0] = ".NET";
      classes[1] = "JAVA";
      classes[2] = "NPTEL";
      classes[3] = "SPorts";
      return classes;
    }
    if (day === "Sunday") {
      var classes = new Array();
      classes[0] = "Closed";
      classes[1] = "Closed";
      classes[2] = "Closed";
      classes[3] = "Closed";
      return classes;
    }
    return false;
  } else if (sec === 2) {
    if (day === "Monday") {
      var classes = new Array();
      classes[0] = "CD";
      classes[1] = "CG/WT";
      classes[2] = "CN";
      classes[3] = "DW";
      return classes;
    }
    if (day === "Tuesday") {
      var classes = new Array();
      classes[0] = "DW";
      classes[1] = "CG/WT";
      classes[2] = "CD";
      classes[3] = "CN";
      return classes;
    }
    if (day === "Wednesday") {
      var classes = new Array();
      classes[0] = "IM";
      classes[1] = "DW";
      classes[2] = "CN-Lab A & CD-Lab B";
      classes[3] = "CD-Lab A & CN-Lab B";
      return classes;
    }
    if (day === "Thursday") {
      var classes = new Array();
      classes[0] = "Apti";
      classes[1] = "Apti";
      classes[2] = "DW-Lab A & CG-lab B/WT-Lab(IT)";
      classes[3] = "CG-Lab A & DW-Lab B";
      return classes;
    }
    if (day === "Friday") {
      var classes = new Array();
      classes[0] = "CN";
      classes[1] = "CD";
      classes[2] = "CG/WT";
      classes[3] = "IS";
      return classes;
    }
    if (day === "Saturday") {
      var classes = new Array();
      classes[0] = ".NET";
      classes[1] = "JAVA";
      classes[2] = "NPTEL";
      classes[3] = "SPorts";
      return classes;
    }
    if (day === "Sunday") {
      var classes = new Array();
      classes[0] = "Closed";
      classes[1] = "Closed";
      classes[2] = "Closed";
      classes[3] = "Closed";
      return classes;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
console.log(fetchCominUp(dayName, section))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Student Resource Portal</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!--This is our header-->

  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm sticky-top navbar-dark bg-primary">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Csians</span></a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myMenu" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
        <!--These are nav items-->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myMenu">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="index.html" class="nav-link active">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Timetable</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="syllabus.html">Syllabus</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Notes</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Events</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contribute</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!--today's time table-->
  <!--we have to use card and make table here-->
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h5>Today's Classes</h5>
        </div>
        <p>
          <button id="cse1" class="btn col-sm-3 col-md-3 btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="">CSE A</button>
          <button id="cse2" class="btn col-sm-3 col-md-3 btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="">CSE B</button>
        </p>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <!--Here i want my section A lectures-->
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <!--Here i want my section B lectures-->

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <!--Footer-->
  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="page-footer fixed-bottom font-small bg-primary">

    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3"><span style="color:white">Handcrafted with </span>
      <i class="fas fa-music"></i><span style="color:white"> and </span>
      <i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i>
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->
  </footer>
  <!-- Footer -->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="/public/main.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#cse1").click(function() {
      fetchCominUp(1);
    })
    $("#cse2").click(function() {
      fetchCominUp(2);
    })
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

[This image is of my html code of the section where I want to show lectures of today - please help me how to show the classes using javascript function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIDYT.png)

jQuery

Below is my jQuery function to fetch the timeTable of cse1 when we click on cse1 button same for cse2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#cse1").click(function() {
        fetchCominUp(1);
    })
    $("#cse2").click(function() {
        fetchCominUp(2);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: please help me how to show today's time table when someone clicks on CSE A , the time table of CSE A shows usinf above javscript function and vice-versa for CSE B.

Comment: If you want to get the data from a database, use [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `fetchCominUp()` expects there to be two arguments, day and sec. You never send the `sec` and hence always return false since all you if/elses fail. PS: arrays can contain other arrays or objects, so you can replace the entire if/else structure with just an array literal or an object.

Comment: You're fetching the data on click, and then? You don't do anything with the returned array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a jsfiddle with your code and fixes to get what you are trying to achieve.

`Here is a link to jsfiddle` [click this link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dq6japgh/)

I have changed some of your code in html and javascript. Works fine now.

Comment: you are welcome. I suggest you to go through jQuery documentation whenever you have time. That will help a lot